# 'Hide out of stock items from the catalog' does not work in WooCommerce when no. of variation (for variable product) is large

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce there is an option to hide the product when it is out of stock using '**Hide out of stock items from the catalog**' checkbox in WooCommerce setting page. It works fine for variable products as long as number of variation is within certain limit,  if the variation is more than the limit it doesn't hide it.

I have observed that it works fine for a product when no. of variation is 24. But when I change the no. of variation to 48, it has stopped working. Although I don't know the exact upper limit beyond which it doesn't work.

For example, I have a product variant 'color = red' and 'size = 34B'. If that product is out of stock then when user select 'red' color in single product page, the size 34B should be disable/cross-marked. This happen when no. of variation is 24. But when I change the no. of variation to 48, it doesn't work. When user select 'red' & '34B', then it says '**out of stock**'.

Is it an issue from WooCommerce plugin side ? Is there any hook to avoid that limitation ?

Wordpress version --> 6.0.3 
WooCommerce version --> Version 7.1.1

Thanks !!!

Note : It is also observed that the below event is used to disable/cross-marked/hide-out the variation, however it doesn't work when variation is large:

```
 $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_has_changed", function () {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **woocommerce_product_query** hook to prevent out-of-stock products will be hidden from the catalog.

```
function hide_out_of_stock_products( $q ) {
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_stock_status',
        'value'   => 'outofstock',
        'compare' => '='
    );
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_out_of_stock_products' );
```